# Filter by ALL columns in row not equal to null (pig)

Tags: apache-pig

Hi I am a little stuck on some logic and was wondering if anyone could give me a tip.  I am trying to filter rows based on multiple columns not being null.  My first thought was something like this:

```
B = FILTER A BY $8!='' AND $9!='' AND $10!='' AND $11!='';
```

But then I realized that will filter out rows where some are null, but not all.  Like if `$8` and `$9` are null, but `$10` and `$11` are not null, they would be filtered out in my example, but I don't want that.  I only want to remove rows where all of `$8`, `$9`, `$10`, `$11` = null.  I am sure it is something simple that I am just not seeing, but I have tried a lot and have googled a lot and still feel stuck.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to understand if your data has blank strings or null values. Nulls have a special meaning in Pig and aren't the same as blanks. To test for nulls you can use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` instead of `== ''` and `!= ''`. Whenever you try use normal comparison operators (like `==`, `>`, etc.) on null values, the result is null instead of true/false. If you're trying to filter, any comparison that results in null will be filtered out. (For example, `var != "apple"` filters out all the rows where `var` is `apple` *and* all the rows where `var` is null.)

To see what you have in your data try:

```
B = FILTER A BY $8 == '';
C = LIMIT B 10;
DUMP;
```

And also:

```
B = FILTER A BY $8 IS NULL;
C = LIMIT B 10;
DUMP;
```

If you get results from the first, you have blanks. If you get results from the second, you have nulls.

To answer your question, if you have blanks you can use this to remove rows where all of the specified fields are blank:

```
B = FILTER A BY NOT ($8 == '' AND $9 == '' AND $10 == '' AND $11 == '');
```

If you have nulls, you can use:

```
B = FILTER A BY NOT ($8 IS NULL AND $9 IS NULL AND $10 IS NULL AND $11 IS NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked beautifully!  Also thanks for the lesson on blank vs. null.  I have filed that away in my notes.